# В моем парсере не находит модуль fake useragent

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Вот мой парсер. Он находит вакансии и забирает их имена и чтобы меня не забанили, я использую fake useragent. Сразу скажу, что я на сайт должен переходит через селениум, так как для дальнейшего обучения буду использовать его. Что тут может быть не так?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
def perehod():
    user=UserAgent()
    profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override',user.random)
    driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    sait=driver.get('https://rabota.ykt.ru/') 
    return sait

#Это смена юзер агента

def navigate(perehod):
    table=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.r-vacancy_list').get_attribute('innerHTML')
    return table

    #Это нахождение всей таблицы селениумом

def rabota(navigate):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(navigate,'lxml')
    vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')
    all_knopki=[]
    for vacansia in vacansii:
        knopka=vacansia.find(class_='r-vacancy_title').text
        all_knopki.append(knopka)
        return all_knopki

    #Это нахождение названий вакансий

def main():
    a=rabota(navigate(perehod()))
    print (a)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Вот код ошибки

```
E:\Python>E:\Python\rabota\parser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\rabota\parser.py", line 6, in <module>
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fake_useragent'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите модуль `fake-useragent`. В `cmd` введите это: `pip install fake-useragent`

Comment: Что такое cmd? cmd-это командная строка? Если что у меня уже установлен fake-useragent в виртуальном окружении